# jQuery UI auto-complete

Tags: css, jquery-ui, styles

I tried to use jQuery UI autocomplete in a RTL page: http://jsfiddle.net/E9w3V/
I converted jquery ui to RTL style using http://cssjanus.commoner.com/.

But its menu does not display properly. What is wrong?

```
<body dir="rtl" style="text-align: center">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../asset/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../asset/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('input').autocomplete({source: ['ddd', 'ss', 'awe', 'fgs', 'i', 'e', 'wt']});
    });
</script>
<input type="text"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using following option solved the problem. ◕‿◕

```
position:{ my: "right top", at: "right bottom", collision: "none" }
```

Comment: Is the result not exactly the same as the first demo I posted?

Comment: @Zeaklous I tried it locally and it works. JSfiddle does not show it correctly. Thanks a lot for your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You were overriding the styles with two sets of jQuery UI code... Remove the one in the CSS panel and it solves itself. [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/E9w3V/3/)

If you still wanted to move the location of the autocomplete, you can use jQuery UI's [`position`](http://jqueryui.com/position/)

However it seems you wanted the auto complete to take up the full width of the viewport. You can do so by binding a function to `autocompleteopen`, setting its width to the `body`'s width, and positioning it where you want it

```
.bind("autocompleteopen", function(event, ui) {
            var top = $(this).offset().top + $(this).scrollHeight;
            $('.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu').css({
                width:$('body').width(),
                position:'absolute',
                top:top + "px",
                left:'0px'
            });
        });
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/E9w3V/4/)

To apply these things to a specific `input`, use the following

```
$('input:eq(0)').autocomplete({source: ['ddd', ..., 'wt']});
```

Otherwise if you want it to apply to every `input`, you can use `$.each`

```
$.each($('input'), function() { 
    $(this).autocomplete({source: ['ddd', ... 'wt']});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see nay difference between the output of your with original version. The suggestion list should be placed exactly under input.

Comment: @PHPst Updated my solution to accommodate

Comment: Perhaps I do not word my question clearly. I want to use the autocomplete widget in a RTL page. Have you tried to make some stuff RTL before?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. So the issue is that the cursor is in the wrong location?

Comment: The suggestion list should be placed exactly under input.